# Error in validate and split records processor kylo

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

I am getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xerial/snappy/SnappyInputStream error** in validate and split records processor in standard-ingest template which i am unable to resolve.

This is happening for both csv and json data.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: please add a details into your question. in which nifi processor error appears? what are the parameters of this processor?

Comment: As i have mentioned in the post,  
Processor name:  validate and split records processor(which is nothing but the executesparkjob processor in nifi). 
Input parameters: JSON file(books1.json from the kylo sample file)

Comment: ExecuteSparkJob?  here is a list of standard nifi processors: https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

Comment: Yes it is custom processor..the source code and nar files can be found from the below link.

https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/integrations/nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-spark-bundle/nifi-spark-processors/src/main/java/com/thinkbiganalytics/nifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.. It was due to mismatch of the jar version of snappy-java.
Initially i had added snappy-java-1.0.4.1 which created the above problem.

After adding snappy-java-1.1.0 to the spark classpath.txt the problem got resolved!